# Istio Telemetry envoy accessLogging not working with extensions providers

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I am trying customize envoy access logs, I am using extensions provider but it does not output anything. If I use below telemetry configuration it outputs default access logs.

```
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: mesh-default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  accessLogging:
    - providers:
      - name: envoy
```

However, When I apply extension provider configuration it stops outputting anything in logs.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: mesh-default
spec:
  meshConfig:
    extensionProviders:
      - name: custom-envoy
        envoyFileAccessLog:
          path: /dev/stdout
          logFormat:
            text: "[%START_TIME%]\n"
```

```
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: mesh-default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  accessLogging:
    - providers:
      - name: custom-envoy
```

anyreason, for not outputting anything with extension providers?